# Multiple featured sizes / images / excerpts

Tags: custom-post-types, images, post-thumbnails

Usually I google but I couldn't find an answer for my problem. Most entrys I found were dealing with adding extra featured image sizes, but not when it comes to having different featured image sizes displayed on the index site embeddeed within a custom div with an option to choose from.

What I try to do is working with columns and give them different options when it comes to their featured image size and options for the excerpt. Because it is a bit difficult to explain what I try to achieve I added an image to illustrate what I try to do. Not with jmasonry though and not with plugins.

I don't expect a solution for this here.. def not since it seems complex what I try to do. But if anybody has an suggestion what to look for or with what approach I could start and look at to solve this. I would def. be very thankful.

To describe it a bit better lets say post box 1 is in

```
<div class="post-box-1">content</div>
```

( which, lets say has a width of 600 px and height of 400px )

and post box 2 looks like this

```
<div class="post-box-2">content</div>
```

( which has a width of 200 px and height of 400 px )

[image: The image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a magazine theme.  The way I do this is with multiple loops.  Each loop requests a number of posts, and displays them with a certain size thumbnail, a certain size headline, and maybe an excerpt.  Then a new loop starts.  The site [fashioncow.com](http://fashioncow.com) uses 4 loops on the home page.  The loop first loads three posts for the slider, the second loads one post for the Beauty section, the third loads three posts for the Trending Now section, and the last loop loads eight posts for the More Obsessions section.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I actually have a theme that has a similar option, but I refuse to copy and steal source code and to use themes for professionell projects so I try to figure it out myself. It provides an option to choose from 4 different layout styles to be displayed on the index site. A loop makes sense, I've seen this before coming with wp-shower themes, but it's not exactley what I'm looking for